# React/Redux: How can I pass this state from one component to another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, components, state

I'm a beginner in React and Redux. I've been working on this project where I finally figured out how to store an array as a state. Now, the only problem I'm having is, trying to figure out how to pass that state to another file.

Here are the two files
-Hue.js
-ColorShop.js

In Hue.js, I made an API and saved the contents into an array of objects called productJSON

Hue.js

```
class Hue extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            productJSON: []
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
    fetch('numberendpoint.json')
    .then(results => {
        return results.json();
    }).then(data => {
        let colorArray = [] //initialize array to receive json data
        for (let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
            colorArray.push(data[i])

        }
    let productJSON = JSON.stringify(productArray)
        this.setState({productJSON: productJSON});
    })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <div className="container2">
        {this.state.productJSON}
    </div>
    </div>

)
}
}
```

Now, I'm trying to pass productJSON to another file in the same folder, ColorShop.js. I need to replace _colors (which was reading from a static json file) with productJSON.

ColorShop.js

```
import Hue from './Hue.js'

const TIMEOUT = 100

Hue productJSON={this.state.productJSON} <---- my attempt to get it to work

export default { // I need to replace '_colors' with productJSON
  getColors: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(_colors), timeout || TIMEOUT),
}
```

I don't want to make another class in ColorShop.js, I just want to import this.state.productJSON into it, is that possible? Any pointers are greatly appreciated!!

Update: used the solution suggested by Rahamin. Now I have this code below, all contained within the the "Hue" class. But I'm still getting errors.

```
import React from 'react'

const TIMEOUT = 100

let productJSON;
class Hue extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      products: [],
    };
    this.getColors = this.getColors.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://tech.work.co/shopping-cart/products.json')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      }).then(data => {

    let colorArray = []
    for (let i =0; i < data.length; i++) {
      colorArray.push(data[i])
      }
    console.log("jsonproduct=" + JSON.stringify(productArray))

    productJSON = JSON.stringify(colorArray)

   this.setState({productJSON: productJSON});

  });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container2">
          {this.state.productJSON}
        </div>
      </div>
      )
    }
}


export default {
  getColors: (cb, timeout) => setTimeout(() => cb(({ productJSON: value})), timeout || TIMEOUT), // here is where I am getting an error -- "value" is undefined. I'm not sure I was meant to put "value" there or something else...very new to React so its conventions are still foreign to me.
}
```

Comment: Use Redux Instead of components state you should declare state in reducer and access it globally where you want. You can easy access the state by store.getState();

Comment: Otherwise you could make some wrapper which will call `fetch` and store the data you have received and then passing it to it's nested `Color` and/or `Hue`. Common React approach afaik.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? If the 'other file' is a helper function, you can just pass it a parameter, as you do in any function in any programming language:

From Hue you call `colorShop(productsJson)` and get back a result that you can render in Hue (`colorShop` starting with a lowercase character, otherwise React will think it is a component). It seems that the 'other file' can just be a function in the Hue.js file...

`ColorShop` can also be a component that gets `productsJson` as a prop and renders it after modification. ColorShop doesn't need to be a class, it can be a functional component. But this doesn't seem to be required by your example.

Here is the code (not complete - see comments) after inserting `colorShop` as a function into the class component. And you can pass it a value and get a returned value, or have it set the state, whatever you like:

```
import React from 'react';

const TIMEOUT = 100;

class Hue extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        productJSON: []
    };
    this.getColors = this.getColors.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('numberendpoint.json')
      .then(results => {
          return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
          let colorArray = []; //initialize array to receive json data
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            colorArray.push(data[i]);
          }
      let productJSON = JSON.stringify(productArray);
          this.setState({ productJSON: productJSON });
      });
    }

    render() {

      // call getColor from wherver you need to call it.
      // for example:
      // getColors();

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="container2">
            {this.state.productJSON}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

  getColors(cb, timeout) {
    setTimeout(() => cb(colors), timeout || TIMEOUT);

    // Here you can setState({ productJSON: value });
    // Or you can return a value to the caller
  }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I tried your example but I'm still producing some errors. I'll replicate them above...if you have time to help me figure out I'm doing incorrectly, I'd really appreciate it (or if any other user does)

Comment: thank you! I'm wondering what I can't pass in ({ productJSON:value }) like that.

Comment: (1) Where do you define productArray? I don't see its definition. (2) I am not familiar with this type of export... Usually I export the class itself...Where is the class being used if you don't export it? The two exported functions are not used by this class, so why are they here? (3) What is 'cb'?

Comment: (1) Sorry, I changed that back to colorArray just now. (2) I just wanted to make a class so that I could do the API call within a class, so the class isn't really being anywhere except in this file. 3) From redux documention:  The middleware will perform a call fn(...arg, cb). The cb is a callback passed by the middleware to fn. If fn terminates normally, it must call cb(null, result) to notify the middleware of a successful result. If fn encounters some error, then it must call cb(error) in order to notify the middleware that an error has occurred.

Comment: Where is productArray being defined? Also, if you don't use this class anywhere, where do you use the data being fetched here? And why not fetching this data in the component using it? You mention redux, but I don't see that you use redux here. Many questions :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! Sorry, colorArray (productArray was my old name for it) is being initialized as an empty array outside the class. Also, my aim is to pass the data to another class outside of this file, so I need a way to store it, hence using Redux

Comment: So this class doesn't seem to be needed... Why not move getColors to the class that needs it? Same for the code in componentDidMount - it seems to belong in the class that needs it...